# Problem while porting VB.NET Code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, struct, casting

Currently I am trying to port some VB.NET code to C#.

The struct looks like this in VB.NET:

```
Public Structure sPos
    Dim x, y, z As Single
    Function getSectorY() As Single
        Return Math.Floor(y / 192 + 92)
    End Function
    Function getSectorX() As Single
        Return Math.Floor(x / 192 + 135)
    End Function
    Function getSectorXOffset() As Int32
        Return ((x / 192) - getSectorX() + 135) * 192 * 10
    End Function
    Function getSectorYOffset() As Int32
        Return ((y / 192) - getSectorY() + 92) * 192 * 10
    End Function
End Structure
```

C# Version of the struct:

```
    public struct sPos
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
        public float getSectorY()
        {
            return (float)Math.Floor(y / 192 + 92);
        }
        public float getSectorX()
        {
            return (float)Math.Floor(x / 192 + 135);
        }
        public Int32 getSectorXOffset()
        {
            return (int)((x / 192) - getSectorX() + 135) * 192 * 10;
        }
        public Int32 getSectorYOffset()
        {
            return (int)((y / 192) - getSectorY() + 92) * 192 * 10;
        }
    }
```

Why do I have to cast the return values to float & int ? In the vb version I don't have to..

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `()` after `getXSectorOffset` because it's a function?

example:

```
nullPointX = pictureBox1.Width / 2 - sectorsize - centerPos.getSectorXOffset() / 10 * sectorsize / 192;
```

Regarding the second question, you could avoid cast to float with this modification:

```
public float getSectorY()
    {
        return (float)Math.Floor(y / 192f + 92f);
    }
```

And sorry, you'll have to cast to `int` still.  Unless you cast the `x` and `getXOffset()` to `int` during the function:

```
public Int32 getSectorXOffset()
    {
        return (((int)x / 192) - (int)getSectorX() + 135) * 192 * 10;
    }
```

Comment: It's a method in a struct, see the bottom of the code the OP added.

Comment: Seriously, I don't know how I could miss something like that. I am ashamed of myself, thank you very much!

Comment: Though, what about the casting question?

Comment: modified answer to include the 2nd answer

Comment: I think the real issue is use of `Option Strict Off` in the VB.Net, so the casts don't have to be written explicitly. Of course this is a bad practise and leads to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you shouldn't use "Dim" on class/structure level variables. Always use Public, Protected, Private etc.

Also note that division works differently in VB and C#. In VB, if you divide two integers like so:

```
Dim r As Double = 5/2
```

Then r will be a Double with value 2.5

In C# however, division with integers gives you integer results, 2 in this case.

Comment: Keep in mind that VB has 2 division operators. / is floating point division and \ is integer division.

Answer (score 2):

If you set **Option Strict On** in your VB code (which you really ought to *always* do) then I think you'd need to cast the return values in VB as well: Math.Floor() returns a Double, not a Single, and you should really tell the compiler that you wanted to lose that precision (which is what the (float) cast in the C# version does) rather than letting the compiler throw precision away without you making an informed decision.